# Using if .present? redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I feel like this is simple but I'm banging my head against the wall. I'm trying to tell my Rails app that if one parameter is present (signature in this example) that I want to redirect home.  Here's my code:

```
<%= if @pc.signature.present? %><% redirect_to "pages#home" %><%end%>
```

I keep running into a syntax error.  This is in the edit.html.erb file by the way.

Comment: You can't redirect in a view. Redirection is done at the controller level. Also, it helps when you're reporting that you get an error, to actually post the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps in your controller you didn't define @pc? also, use path instead of 'pages#home'. it should look more like this:

```
def edit
  @pc = Pc.find(params[:id]) #or whatever your logic is
  redirect_to root_path if @pc.signature.present?
  # otherwise 'edit' template will be rendered
end
```

Comment: Worked perfectly - you're right, I neglected to define @pc. Modified that and swapped path in and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do that on your action controller, not in the view

```
def your_action
  if @pc.signature.present?
    redirect_to 'your_path_or_url' 
  end
end
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me either! `class PcsController < ApplicationController    def edit
    if @pc.signature.present?
      redirect_to 'pages#home' 
    end
  end`

Comment: @PSCampbell You aren't telling us why it's not working, so we can't help you.

Comment: `pages#home` is not a real url in the controller (only in routing), perhaps you want something like `pages_path(:page => :home)` ?